# How to Change word in file using Batch file

Tags: batch

I try unsuccessfully to change word in text file(D:\comp.txt) using Batch

File path: D:\comp.txt

Old word: server12

My new word: server777

Can someone can help me with the script syntax ??

I tried to use [BatchSubstitute.bat](http://www.dostips.com/?t=Batch.FindAndReplace) with no success .
 VBscript will be OK ether. 
Thanks

Comment: Superuser isn't a script-writing service. Please post exactly what you tried, and what happened when you ran it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23285047/how-replace-a-word-in-a-text-file-using-a-bat-file

Comment: I just need the right direction.

Comment: See [this eichhorn's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16919148/3439404)

Comment: Checkout FART if you have a chance---http://fart-it.sourceforge.net/ . . . .It may suit your need perhaps if you've not gotten something else figured out already.